# T-sql. Что будет находиться в переменной типа int если select ничего не вернет?

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @result int;

set @result = (select sum(quantity) ...)
```

Что находится в переменной result, если запрос ничего не возвращает?

Необходимо, если запрос ничего не вернет - поместить в переменную 0. 
Пробовал присвоить переменной значение 0 до выборки select, но после выборки там не 0.

Пробовал:

```
if (@result = null or @result < 0)
    set @result = 0;
```

Предположу, что можно использовать Exists для проверки вернет ли мой запрос что нибудь. Но в таком случае код дублируется дважды. Первый раз для проверки, второй для присваивания переменной.

Comment: C `NULL` надо сравнивать не через `= null`, а через `is null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Что находится в переменной result, если запрос ничего не возвращает?

NULL, ясен пень...

> Необходимо, если запрос ничего не вернет - поместить в переменную 0.

```
set @result = COALESCE((select sum(quantity) ...), 0)
```

Comment: Если ясен пень, почему не отработал мой код? (там где проверка на null и присваивание значения)

Comment: @АндрейТищенко Потому что вы проверяли `@result = null`, а нужно `@result is null`

Comment: @АндрейТищенко NULL - это, в просторечии, "фиг знает". То есть ты пытаешься узнать, равно ли одно "фиг знает" другому "фиг знает". Или равно ли какое-то число и "фиг знает". Результат в обоих случаях очевиден - а вот "фиг знает". Да, `@result = null` даёт NULL, и неважно, чему равен `@result`.

Comment: @Akina, если совсем строго, то `@result = NULL` дает `UNKNOWN`, а не `NULL`. Но это всё равно ни разу не `TRUE`, и поэтому в ветку `THEN` мы не попадем. Пруф: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Ну тогда ещё надо упомянуть про `SET ANSI_NULLS`, который запросто может сделать NULL пусть и особым, но тем не менее определённым, значением, пригодным к сравнению.

Comment: Про `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` я бы не рассказывал новичкам до последнего. Примерно как про `git push --force` :)